# Return data without including that data in the comparison

Tags: sql

I am using the below code:

```
SELECT l_name, f_name, user_id
FROM (SELECT a.l_name, a.f_name, count(*)
      FROM shema.emp_table1 a, schema2.emp_table2 b
     WHERE     a.emp_id = b.emp_id2
           AND b.office_num = '4017'
           AND a.email IS NULL
    HAVING COUNT (a.l_name) > 1
    group by a.l_name, a.f_name
    ORDER BY a.l_name, a.f_name)
GROUP BY l_name, f_name;
```

...what I WANT to do is return the users Last Name, First Name AND User ID, IF the users in the database 'match up' on Last Name (potential duplicates).  Where I'm running into problems is that the USER_ID field is going to be unique for each user...so even though they may share a last and first name, the user ID is unique...and this is causing my query to return zero rows.  If I eliminate the user ID field from the search criteria, I get the list I'm looking for:  Users who share a last and first name...(for instance Doe, John with a count of 4).  But even though I don't want the query against the User ID, I DO want it as one of the 'returned fields'...but I can't seem to get it to do that.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.  I've tried many different variations of the above query, with/without counts inside and out, with/without user_id inside and out, etc., and so far no luck in getting what I'm looking for.

What I'd like to have as output would be something like:

```
L_NAME                 F_NAME                  USER_ID               COUNT(*)
SMITH                  JOHN                    ABC123                2
SMITH                  JOHN                    BCD234                2
```

...although, now that I'm looking for it, the query may not work because the 'count(*)' won't be 2 for Smith, John with a User ID of ABC123...the 'User ID' is causing it to be more difficult than I'd like.  Do I need to write an anomyous block to fill this kind of request?

Thanks!

Comment: if the `user_id` values are different, which one do you want to see?

Comment: also, are the `user_id` values different between `shema.emp_table1` and 'schema2.emp_table2',or are there several rows within each table that share first and last name?

Answer (score 0):

If you return the data from the sub-query, and join it to the outer-query with the same qualifiers in both the sub and outer queries, it should work.  I don't have your tables so I can't test this, so you may have to tweak it a bit.

```
SELECT x.l_name, x.f_name, a1.emp_id, x.cnt
FROM  (
        SELECT a.l_name, a.f_name, count(*) as CNT
        FROM   schema.emp_table1 a, schema2.emp_table2 b
        WHERE  a.emp_id = b.emp_id2
          AND  b.office_num = '4017'
          AND  a.email IS NULL
        HAVING COUNT (a.l_name) > 1
        GROUP BY a.l_name, a.f_name
        ORDER BY a.l_name, a.f_name
      ) as x
      INNER JOIN schema.emp_table1 a1 on x.l_name = a1.l_name
      INNER JOIN schema2.emp_table2 b1 on x.l_name = b1.l_name and a1.emp_id = b1.emp_id2
WHERE  b1.office_num = '4017'
  AND  a1.email IS NULL
```